# Kaminari Ajax paginate doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, kaminari

I have below view and controller. Though `remote: true` is mentioned, kaminari calls my method using `http`(using page refresh). Is there anything i am missing to make my kaminari links **ajaxable**.

**In VIEWS:**

```
<div id="paginate">
  <%= paginate @user, params: {slug: nil, pgsz: 20}, remote: true %>
</div>
```

**In Controller:**

```
@user = Kaminari.paginate_array(@properties, total_count: @search_result.total_count).page(params[:page]).per(params[:pgsz] ||= 20)
```

I will be responding to ajax in my controller, but first it doesn't even make an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because you don't have `jquery_ujs` loaded, check your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, it should have these two lines (at least):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: u just saved my day bro !! thanks much ..is this documented anywhere that i missed ?

Comment: Probably not because it's the default Rails setup (ie. you have to remove those lines after creating a Rails app). There's probably a mention of it in the docs for the `:remote` option for `form_for` or `link_to` or something.